# SvcUtil.exe Generate multiple wsdl files

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

I've made a project in Visual C# 2008 Express with several interfaces with a service contract. I generate a WSDL from this using the scvutil.exe tool. All this works perfectly: I get a nice and working WSDL file. However I would like the tool to generate separate WSDL files for the different interfaces. Now it puts everything together in one big WSDL file. Is there a way to do this without just putting all these interfaces in separate projects and than generating WSDL files one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think there's a way to do this.

Comment: He's right.  The only way to do this is to create multiple projects.